# Не могу вставить картинку

Tags: android, resources, android-resources

Ошибок при компиляции нет, но картинки не выводятся - только три голубых квадратика

java

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.inv);
TextView textEl = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

int strId = getResources().getIdentifier("article", "string", getPackageName());
String strValue = getString(strId);
textEl.setText(Html.fromHtml(strValue));
```

xml

```
<string name="article" formatted="false"><![CDATA[
<img src="@res/mipmap-hdpi/ic_launcher">
<img src="@res/mipmap-hdpi/ic_launcher.png">
<img src="file:///С:/Android/testV7/app/src/main/res/qwerty.png"/>
```

разметка

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Go to Activity One"
            android:id="@+id/btnActOne"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <Button
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button 1" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
                android:text="nope"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button 11" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Покажите разметку, возможно у вас картинка маленького разрешения и wrap_content на ширину и высоту выставлено.

Comment: .так и есть             <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
                android:text="nope"
                 />  но у меня в textView выводятся не только картинки, но и текст с html разметкой

Comment: атрибут "fill_parent" давно не используется. Обновите ответ вместе со всей имеющейся разметкой.

Comment: я добавил код в вопросе

Comment: Есть специальные кнопки, называемые Image Button или Image View  - в вашей разметке нет ни одного подобного. Используйте их для вывода картинок. `TextView` это не тот виджет, который используется для отображения фото или иных изображений.

Comment: я вывожу хтмл код в текствью которое можно скроллить. как вы себе представляете запихивание в него кнопок? резать текствью на 100 мелких - совсем не вариант

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43724/discussion-between-asgard-and-).

Comment: у меня нет в чате поля для написания сообщений

Comment: посмотрите внизу.

Comment: You must have 20 reputation on The Stack Exchange Network to talk here. See the faq.

Comment: значит подкопите репутации, пока низя)

Comment: i have 24 reputation/ wtf?

Comment: история умалчивает)

Comment: ну ладно, буду писать тут)

Comment: я заменил текствью на это            <WebView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_gravity="right" />

Comment: при открытии активити программа крашится

Comment: не используйте fill_parent никогда более, посмотрите на ответ ниже и попробуйте сделать так.

Answer (score 1):

Я так понимаю вы хотите поместить в TextView html текст с картинками. TextView не выводят картинки, они предназначены только для текста, для ваших целей целесообразнее использовать [WebView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html). Так же советую html документы хранить в Assets, специальная папка для стилей, вместо ресурсов. 
Наипростейшее его использование:

```
WebView wv= (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/yourfile.html");
```

Так же можно использовать парсинг документа, например через jsoup, и уже с помощью него строить xml файл в андроиде.